# AttributeError when trying to set a window type hint with GTK using Python

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk

I'm still really new to python, so this will probably be a dumb question.

I'm trying to learn how to make a GUI using pygtk (Mostly because I use linux and I'd like to have GTK theming support in my programs). I've started with the most simple window possible, and I've found that since I'm using a tiling window manager the program will be tiled.

This is not a problem, but the first program I wanted to make needs a floating window, and I could fix it client-side modifying the configuration of the window manager, but I'd like to do it right and make it working for everyone.

[After some research](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/61/forcing-windows-as-always-floating.1.html) I've found that the way to do it is by setting a window type hint that the window manager will automatically set as "floating". This is what I've tried, using [this](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--set-type-hint) as resource:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.set_type_hint(Gtk.gdk.WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_UTILITY)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

But it doesn't work. I get a traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/storHDD/Programming/Python/python-learning/guitesting.py", line 7, in <module>
    win.set_type_hint(Gtk.gdk.WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_UTILITY)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gi/overrides/__init__.py", line 39, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._introspection_module, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gi/module.py", line 139, in __getattr__
    self.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'gdk'
```

I don't really know what to do from here. I've tried to import gdk too, but it doesn't seem to change anything. Any idea about what can I do to solve this?

Comment: pygtk is __not__ Gtk3. Whenever you see pygtk code, it's likely outdated and won't work with Gtk3. `gtk.gdk` is an example of that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't. Thanks for the answer though. Since according to Rawing this is because pygtk is outdated is there any better way to do things?

Comment: This seems perfect to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import `Gdk`, then use `Gdk.WindowTypeHint.UTILITY`, not `Gtk.gdk.WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_UTILITY`:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.set_type_hint(Gdk.WindowTypeHint.UTILITY)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

[image]

see also [here](https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/Gdk-3.0/Gdk.WindowTypeHint.html).